# How to implement user hierarchy with different levels of roles under different branches, groups etc

Tags: 7, users

I have to create a web portal, that should have a number of users from super administrator to employee. Users have single or multilevel access (either to data of one branch or to multiple) on the system.

Some can add/edit data and some can only view some data. The system has different branches, different departments etc.. How can I implement such a system using Drupal?

I had created multiple roles and given permissions to them. But how can I achieve those multi branch multi groups kind of user hierarchy?

**Update**:
Can I achieve it by using TAC : https://www.drupal.org/node/31601 ?

Comment: The question really is to broad. One could write a book on the topic of "web portal on Drupal". There's just two many options.

Comment: Hi, this is currently much too broad a question for our Q+A format so I've refunded the bounty. Please either edit the question to make it much narrower in scope (following your own research into what you need to do), or ask a series of new, more focused questions. Please see the [help] for more information on how best to structure and ask questions here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og).

Im using it for a similar use-case. I would allow you to create content types that can act as 'Departments' and add different roles within those.

You can have for example:

- 'department' content types with following roles: admin, supervisor
- 'branch' content type with completely different roles: it programmer, temp

It is very flexible and access control works with views as well. Nice tutorial can be found [here](http://vimeo.com/28175341).

If you opt to however to write your custom access control module, make sure that you read up on that [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/270000)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It would really depend on what your data is and how it's stored/ displayed.  You could use TAC or maybe something like [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) and if the provided access control isn't enough, you could use [Organic Groups Access Roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_access_roles).

You have plenty of options, maybe you could describe your portal a little more?